# iOS: Google Maps API - Disable info window tap event

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

The Google Maps api has a `didTapInfoWindowOf` method that can detect when an info window of a marker has been tapped on.

I am trying to limit this event to only one tap for a period of time.

When I tap on the info window I am making an api call to a backend server and when I get a response back I segue to a different view. The problem is that the user can tap on this info window multiple times thus triggering the api call multiple times.

Is there a way to limit this?

At the moment I am using a locally defined property `didTapWindowCount` and limit the api call each time it's tapped like so:

```
var didTapInfoWindowCount = 0
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        didTapInfoWindowCount += 1

        // perform api call -- limit to once until done
        if didTapInfoWindowCount == 1 {
            myAPICall {
                // on success
                didTapInfoWindowCount = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a work around or if there is something built into the API?

Answer (score 0):

`mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker)` will be called as many times as the user taps on the `info window` of the `marker`.

In order to avoid calling it multiple times in case of API hit, you can use a `Bool` value.

```
var didTapInfoWindow = false
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker)
{
    if !didTapInfoWindow
    {
        didTapInfoWindow = true
        myAPICall {
            // on success
            didTapInfoWindow = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asides from the bool value, is there any difference than the way I've done it with the count?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way of doing that.